# Problem with : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null" when trying to code with Javascript. Further information below

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

window.addEventListener("keydown", moveSomething, false);

var dx = 0;
var dy = 0;


function moveSomething(e)
{
 switch(e.keycode)
 {
 case 37: //left key
  dx -= 2;
  break;
  
 case 38: //up key
  dy += 2;
  break;
  
 case 39: //right key
  dx += 2;
  break;
  
 case 40: //down key
  dy -= 2;
  break;
 
 }

 drawRect();
}

 

function drawRect()
{
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(250 + dx, 200 + dy , 25, 25);
ctx.fillStyle = "green";
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();
}
```

```css
* { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
canvas { background: #eee; display: block; margin: 0 auto; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>basic game</title> 
 </head>
 
 <body>
 <canvas id="myCanvas" height="500px" width="500px"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to code a simple program where you can move a rectangle around a canvas using the keys.

For some reason when I load it I get the following error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null"

This is confusing me as I have coded another game with this but I didn't get this error.

Also, I have tried to use the "window.onload=function(){}" solution but that didn't seem to help.

Any advice and help would be greatly appreciated, Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here `document.querySelector("myCanvas")`. querySelector takes css selectors and myCanvas is id for the canvas.
It needs to be: **document.querySelector("#myCanvas")**

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("#myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

window.addEventListener("keydown", moveSomething, false);

var dx = 0;
var dy = 0;


function moveSomething(e)
{
 switch(e.keycode)
 {
 case 37: //left key
  dx -= 2;
  break;
  
 case 38: //up key
  dy += 2;
  break;
  
 case 39: //right key
  dx += 2;
  break;
  
 case 40: //down key
  dy -= 2;
  break;
 
 }

 drawRect();
}

 

function drawRect()
{
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(250 + dx, 200 + dy , 25, 25);
ctx.fillStyle = "green";
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();
}
```

```css
* { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
canvas { background: #eee; display: block; margin: 0 auto; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>basic game</title> 
 </head>
 
 <body>
 <canvas id="myCanvas" height="500px" width="500px"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `document.querySelector`, but you're passing it a raw ID instead of a CSS selector. To fix it, use `document.getElementById` instead:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

window.addEventListener("keydown", moveSomething, false);

var dx = 0;
var dy = 0;


function moveSomething(e)
{
 switch(e.keycode)
 {
 case 37: //left key
  dx -= 2;
  break;
  
 case 38: //up key
  dy += 2;
  break;
  
 case 39: //right key
  dx += 2;
  break;
  
 case 40: //down key
  dy -= 2;
  break;
 
 }

 drawRect();
}

 

function drawRect()
{
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(250 + dx, 200 + dy , 25, 25);
ctx.fillStyle = "green";
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();
}
```

```css
* { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
canvas { background: #eee; display: block; margin: 0 auto; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>basic game</title> 
 </head>
 
 <body>
 <canvas id="myCanvas" height="500px" width="500px"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```